# Make picklist value setable on creation or by admin only

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule

I have a picklist of stages - let's use the example stages below:

```
Unqualified <- Default / Record creation state
Qualified
Enrolled
Under Review
Active
```

Where as this record progresses through the stages, I would like the value of unqualified to be settable only for record creation or by admins.

Any other ideas besides:

- Make a validation rule that does not allow the value of `Unqualified` to be set where user profile != Sys Admin.
- Make a validation rule that does not allow value of `Unqualified` to be set after record creation? (Not sure how to do this)

Comment: Use different record types. The record types option gives you control the pick list values. This may be an option.

This may have some dependency with your existing process. Please check that also once.

Comment: @KSL Comments are generally for clarification. You should consider adding this as an answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Thanks. I added it.

Answer (score 1):

Use different record types. The record types option gives you control on the pick list values. This may be an option. This may have some dependency with your existing process. Please check that also once.